# Attempting to unserialize an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, serialization, cookies

```
if ($delete_one == null && $delete_two == null && $delete_three == null) {
    echo "THE CONTENT SHOULD BE GRABED ONCE";
    $arr = array("foo" => "bar", 12 => "one");
    echo $arr["foo"];
    echo $arr[12];
    $serialize_arr = serialize($arr);
    setcookie("test", $serialize_arr);

}
else
{
    echo " THIS PART WORKS! ";
    $arr_ser = $_COOKIE["test"];
    $arr = unserialize($arr_ser);
    var_dump(arr_ser);
    var_dump($arr);
    if ($arr == null) {
        echo "   Why is there nothing in here??   ";
    }
     else
    {
        echo "There is something in this array!";
    }   
}
```

The cookie is set when non of the $delete_one, two or three are used and when the user submits the form one of these elements change thus completing the else statement. The cookie is brought back in and the var_dump(arr_ser) will display it showing the serialized array. However the unserialize doesn't work. It is false and I am unsure why the unserialization does not work.

I've tried what Raisen said and looked through the PHP manual and tried to emulate what the examples show. I've created two if statements the second one being a replica of the example and the other is slightly changed to put other content into an array. The example works but the changes I've made does not. NOTE: I'm using this in the back-end of WordPress to create a plugin.

```
if ($delete_one == null && $delete_two == null && $delete_three == null) {
    $arr [foo] = "bar"; 
    $arr [boo] = "one";
    $serialize_arr = gzcompress(serialize($arr), 9);
    setcookie("test", $serialize_arr, time()+60*60*24*60, '/');

}
else
{
    if(isset($_COOKIE[test])) {
        $array = unserialize(gzuncompress($_COOKIE[test]));
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($array);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}   

if ($delete_one == null && $delete_two == null && $delete_three == null) {  
    $data[qwerty] = "blah";
    $data[1][a] = "1aa";
    $data[2][b] = "2bb";
    $data[3][c] = ";;;;;;";
    $data[name][first] = "Bob";
    $data[name][last] = "Jones";
    $data[val] = "This is a real long test string, to see how well the compression works!";

    $string = gzcompress(serialize($data), 9);
    setcookie("my_var", $string, time()+60*60*24*60, '/');
}
else
{
    if(isset($_COOKIE[my_var])) {
        $array = unserialize(gzuncompress($_COOKIE[my_var]));
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($array);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

The content doesn't unserialize thus gzuncompress has a data error.

Comment: Try this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php#47809

Comment: What's the output of your two `var_dump(arr_ser); var_dump($arr);`? (You've got a missing `$` there BTW.)

Comment: Thanks your right, I added that and string(38) "x�K�2��.�2�RJ��W����`,�X~^��u-\08� _" for the var_dump($arr_ser) and var_dump($arr) is  bool(false). However in the original post var_dump($arr_ser); would display the array serialzed and var_dump($arr) would post bool(false)

Comment: So the cookie apparently contains gibberish?

Comment: Well I was thinking that the gibberish is coming from the gzcompress. But my only rational is that is one of the major things I have changed. If you physically look at the cookie it has a content of x%DAK%B42%B2%AA.%B62%B6RJ%CB%CFW%B2%06%B3%92%12%8B%60%2C%B8X%7E%5E%AA%92u-%008%89%0D_  Note as well the gzuncompress has a data error.

Comment: I've confirmed that the gzcompress was creating the gibberish. The var_dump($arr_ser); now returns string(54) "a:2:{s:3:\"foo\";s:3:\"bar\";s:3:\"boo\";s:3:\"one\";}"

Comment: I solved the problem by creating a cookie array to store the data I needed.

Comment: observation on this, why use cookies at all in this way? Surely it's more secure to use sessions and store the info in $_SESSION so that it isn't transmitted to the client?

Comment: Interesting I came here after searching for a string on google related to a hack in 2008. So some silly hacker is using this forum to help themselves hack websites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are having is pretty simple and shown in your comment:

> I've confirmed that the gzcompress was
>   creating the gibberish. The
>   var_dump($arr_ser); now returns
>   string(54)
>   "a:2:{s:3:\"foo\";s:3:\"bar\";s:3:\"boo\";s:3:\"one\";}"

you have either magic_quotes_runtime and/or magic_quotes_gps turned on. the value of the cookie has been run through AddSlashes(), so is no longer a valid serialized object. the simple fix is to either disable those options, or change this line:

```
$arr_ser = $_COOKIE["test"];
```

to this:

```
$arr_ser = StripSlashes($_COOKIE["test"]);
```

Comment: An hour of wondering why unserialize was returning false led to this, thank you. I figured there was something added in the cookie process.